# Navigate to a screen by it's name in PowerApps

Tags: powerapps

Let's say I have a [dropdown](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/tutorials/control-drop-down/) control in my PowerApps application with the next items:

```
[
    "1. Calculator", 
    "2. Counter", 
    "3. API", 
    "4. Collections", 
    "5. Dropdown", 
    "6. Acceleration", 
    "7. Camera"
]
```

And I want to navigate to a screen by it's name. Something like

```
Navigate(Nav.Selected.Value, ScreenTransition.Cover)
```

Is it possible to do somehow? **Is there a function that returns a control by it's name?**

```
Navigate(GetControl(Nav.Selected.Value), ScreenTransition.Cover)
```

Because now I have to use [If](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/tutorials/function-if/) function to navigate in the app like this:

```
Navigate(If(
    "1" in Nav.Selected.Value, Screen1, 
    "2" in Nav.Selected.Value, Screen2, 
    "3" in Nav.Selected.Value, Screen3, 
    "4" in Nav.Selected.Value, Screen4, 
    "5" in Nav.Selected.Value, Screen5, 
    "6" in Nav.Selected.Value, Screen6, 
    "7" in Nav.Selected.Value, Screen7), 
ScreenTransition.Cover)
```

which does not look very nice. Is there more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can find a way of achieve that here: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/PowerApps-Forum/Navigate-to-a-screen-by-it-s-name/m-p/2454#M1352

basically creating a table and binding to that instead.

Adding more since this post was deleted claiming it was not giving the details so just cloning the link above:
Create a Table like:

```
    Table(
  { Text: "1. Calculator", Screen: Screen1 },
  { Text: "2. Counter", Screen: Screen2 },
  { Text: "3. API", Screen: Screen3 },
  { Text: "4. Collections", Screen: Screen4 },
  { Text: "5. Dropdown", Screen: Screen5 },
  { Text: "6. Acceleration", Screen: Screen6 },
  { Text: "7. Camera", Screen: Screen7 })
```

and then bind the dropdown to that table and use:

> Navigate(Dropdown1.Selected.Screen, ScreenTransition.Fade)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12580577)

Comment: It does answer the question and it does comment the solution so not sure why it was deleted